# What should we do with the Arduino.cc promotion link?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A while ago, when i proposed this site, i put up a link on the [Arduino playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/) to the Area 51 proposal of Arduino:

[image: arduino.cc sidebar]

Now that we're public, should i change it to link to he actual site? Should i delete it entirely?

**Note:** i will make the necessary changes once we arrive at a conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely change it to the main site now. Don't delete it as it's good promotion of the site.

Comment: It's down at the bottom in small print. Should i change this also?

Comment: @TheDoctor Yes, definitely. (As long as you don't get in any trouble) It is good advertising and we need traffic, especially since currently we're not in Google.

Comment: OK, edited! http://playground.arduino.cc/

Answer (score 6):

AskUbuntu was launched by Stack Exchange and Canonical and is now linked to prominently from the top bar of Ubuntu.com

[image]

Ask Ubuntu is also linked to from the installation GUI. This is beneficial for the site as it generates a lot of traffic.

I think we should also aim for more visibility within the Arduino platform.

We should be here:
[image]

Also, if you open the Arduino IDE, it links back to Arduino.cc from the Help menu. We should be there as well, alongside Arduino.cc

Both of these however, are more long term goals, and will most likely require the support of Stack Exchange, due to Arduino trademark issues.

Comment: That's outside my range of edification

Comment: Found this question again, but the reason it's there is because Canonical had a special agreement with SE. I'm sure if Arduino SE permitted, we could get that, but (as of now) we aren't any official support.